# flask and Jinja2 control structure doesn't work with render_template.format but works when passing the variable directly

Tags: python, flask

Here is a MRE.

`templates/index.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {{test}} {% if test %}lol{% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

`my_test.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template("index.html", test=True)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # local run
    app.run()
```

This works perfectly.

However, when using the `.format` syntax, to output a variable I need to do `{test}` instead of `{{test}}` (which is fine, i don't mind) but more importantly, the `{% if ...}{% endif %}` doesn't work anymore. Any reason why? I can't understand the difference and I don't know how to google it (I've tried reading https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/templating/ but I'm not sure I got any answer).

**My question is to have an explanation of why this behaves like this. I evidently do know how to make the %if% works but my whole project uses `.format()` and I was wondering if I really needed to change everything and if there wouldn't be any drawbacks* in doing so.**

*EDIT: I found that if I did `{my_variable}` with `my_variable` containing a `<br>` it used to do a linebreak but with `{{my_variable}}` (not using `.format`), the `<br>` literally appears. So I guess, I'm not actually finding a way to make it work and I need some help.

EDIT2:
By `using .format()` I mean:

```py
def index():
    return render_template("index.html").format(test=True)
```

and `index.html` would look like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    {test} {% if test %}lol{% endif %}
  </body>
</html>
```

and the `if` statement won't work (`test` will be displayed correctly though).

Comment: Can you post an example where you're using `.format`—I'm not sure if I know what you mean by that.

Comment: Done, sorry i didn't earlier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to use two different forms of replacement:

1. Flask's built in templating with Jinja (`render_template`)
2. Python's built-in `format` method for strings.

You likely want to do one or the other, not both. For constructing an HTML page, #1 is the better option (though you can do some wild things with just `format`), Jinja is purpose built for this task and allows you to do additional things, e.g. conditionals (if/else), loops, etc. Those are all constructs that are valuable when constructing HTML that `format` doesn't support.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Should I just stick if #1 by default? Also, is there a part of the documentation I completely missed? I know it's not particularly important now that I have the explanation, but I'm still confused as to how I'd missed it.

Comment: Jinja has it's own documentation hosted over [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.1.x/templates/). Flask uses it under the hood, but it's its own standalone library—thus the full documentation is separate. But yes. Stick with #1 for this case—`format` is designed for simple replacement in strings, Jinja is designed for templating which is a whole lot more than simple string replacement.